# Alice stole a package from Bob. Is it legal?

Tags: theft, is-x-legal, conversion

Alice stole Bob's Amazon package and opened it. It contained sheets of processed wood, 216 by 365 millimeters. Is this legal?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pun, not a question.

Comment: I'm upvoting because I love a good pun.

Answer (score 1):

### No!

Not unless ther is something to the situation not mentioned in the question. Taking the property of another person without permission is usually theft, and that is a crime.

Why do you think it might be legal? You used the word "stole" in the question, and tht normally indicates a crime.

Comment: The dimensions given transpose two digits from the metric dimensions of legal size paper. It was likely a typo in a joke question.

Comment: @Someone I see "Is it legal" meaning "is it legasl size paper? Very funny. I enjoy puns, riddlwes, but this one wasn't a  good idea, in my view. If this was serious, please explain further. If not, please don't do that again.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the same as any other theft of a similar low-value item. And no, that is not legal size paper. Legal paper is 216 x 3**56** mm.

Comment: 216x365 mm is exactly what OP claims is in the box. It's not SCOTUS paper, which is 155.5 x 235 mm (approx.) Legal is 216 x 356 mm. OP might have ordered a non.-standard size.